# assert.h no such file or directory (Ubuntu 20.04 arm64)

Tags: 20.04, gcc, linux-headers

I tried to solve this problem by installing the various libraries but still nothing. Advice?

[image]

I checked the include path:

[image]

```
parallels@ubuntu-linux-20-04-desktop:~$ locate /assert.h | grep assert.h$
/opt/ros/noetic/include/ros/assert.h
/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/include/assert.h
/usr/include/assert.h

parallels@ubuntu-linux-20-04-desktop:~$ dpkg -l | grep libc6-dev
ii libc6-dev:arm64          2.31-0ubuntu9.3         arm64     GNU C Library: Development Libraries and Header Files
ii libc6-dev-arm64-cross    2.31-0ubuntu9.2cross1   all       GNU C Library: Development Libraries and Header Files (for cross.compliling)

parallels@ubuntu-linux-20-04-desktop:~$ dpkg -L libc6-dev-arm64-cross | grep assert.h
/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/include/assert.h
```

Answer (score 1):

[Install `libc6-dev-arm64-cross`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libc6-dev-arm64-cross) with

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-dev-arm64-cross
```

The [file list](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/all/libc6-dev-arm64-cross/filelist) includes `assert.h`.
So if you install this package, the file will be in your system.

If, when compiling, the header is not found, then it is because it is not in the search path.
So you should clarify exactly which commands/package you used to try compiling.

[Check your include path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980819/what-are-the-gcc-default-include-directories) with

```
avr-gcc -xc -E -v -
```

or

```
echo | gcc -Wp,-v -x c++ - -fsyntax-only
```

Also check where is `assert.h` located with

```
sudo updatedb
locate /assert.h | grep assert.h$
```

If these do not match (I wouldn't know why this is not set correctly automatically), as a workaround you can [add the path by hand](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24232755/2707864).
You can also try [setting it more permanently](https://www.wikitechy.com/tutorials/linux/how-to-add-a-default-include-path-for-gcc-in-linux).

See also

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558803/how-to-add-a-default-include-path-for-gcc-in-linux
2. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html
3. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Environment-Variables.html
4. https://commandlinefanatic.com/cgi-bin/showarticle.cgi?article=art026
5. https://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/how-does-avr-gccg-know-default-include-directories

---

It helps if you post the output of the following commands

```
dpkg -l | grep libc6-dev
dpkg -L libc6-dev-arm64-cross | grep assert.h
```

It is much more useful if you copy-paste the text and format as code, instead of images (a little more work for you, though).

Comment: I did, but the problem still isn't solved

Comment: @NICCOLOERASMI - If the problem is not solved, please post exactly what you tried, and exactly what you obtained. Otherwise, it is almost impossible to help you.

Comment: I inserted the image

Comment: yes, I'm using #include <assert.h>

Comment: I inserted the image

Comment: parallels@ubuntu-linux-20-04-desktop:~$ locate /assert.h | grep assert.h$
/opt/ros/noetic/include/ros/assert.h
/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/include/assert.h
/usr/include/assert.h

Comment: @NICCOLOERASMI - There's the problem. The package installed `/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/include/assert.h` as expected.
But `/usr/aarch64-linux-gnu/include` is not an include path...

Comment: so how do i solve the problem?

Comment: sorry for the images but this is my first time in ubuntuask

Comment: @NICCOLOERASMI - Not a problem. Take 5-10 minutes to read the links and try what is posted.